# Uninstalling Compass breaks CI builds

Tags: ruby, travis-ci, compass

Is there a way I can get a list of what/where Compass installs things when I set up a project? I would like to move away from using Compass and deal with SASS directly.

Nothing against Compass, it's great, but I've found it to be too much for my needs :(

While I have removed the gem (along with the rbenv shim) and migrated my config over to a YAML file in my project, Travis cannot build the site. Looking at the [error](https://github.com/Compass/compass/issues/1928), it seems like CI expects there to be a travis.yml file, but I never configured one to begin with, IIRC.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. Travis CI connectivity was flaky and the service needed to be deleted from the GitHub side.